# How to disable specific domains using CORS in Web API2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have enabled CORS using "System.Web.Http.Cors" and want to block out certain domains. I want to make this dynamic, i.e. the domains which have rights would be picked from APP SETTINGS which I am managing from Azure. To do this, I have implemented "ICorsPolicyProvider" in below way:

```cs
public class EnableCorsAttribute: Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider
{
    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public EnableCorsAttribute(string appSettingOriginKey)
    {
        _policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        // loads the origins from AppSettings
        string originsString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(appSettingOriginKey);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(originsString))
        {
            foreach (var origin in originsString.Split(','))
            {
                _policy.Origins.Add(origin);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

But still it is allowing all the domains. Any thoughts or suggestions?